# If a data type is numeric in database how to check it's precision and scale using java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I can check name of columns using this code

```
Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9823/postgres", "postgres", "password");
DatabaseMetaData md = jdbcConnection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getColumns("postgres", null, "my_table", "%");
while (rs.next()) 
{
  System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
}
```

How check precision and scale of a numeric datatype in any column?

Comment: [According to the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) this is in column #7 and #9

Answer (score 4):

You can find out the meta data of columns through `ResultSetMetaData`. You can get the meta data as following:

```
ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery("blah");
ResultSetMetaData md = rset.getMetaData();
```

Once you got the `ResultSetMetaData`, call the following to get precision and scale:

```
int getPrecision(int column)
int getScale(int column)
```